# Echo HTML tags from PHP variable correctly in OpenCart

Tags: php, html, mysql, opencart, opencart2.x

I am trying to directly output HTML stored within my MySQL database as HTML, but the browser is rendering it as plain text.

I am working within OpenCart so I am not sure if there are references in other pages that may be affecting my code.

This is where I am defining the variable from the MySQL array

```
$results = $this->model_catalog_manufacturer->getManufacturers();
   foreach ($results as $result) {
      if (is_numeric(utf8_substr($result['name'], 0, 1))) {
            $key = '0 - 9';
        } else {
            $key = utf8_substr(utf8_strtoupper($result['name']), 0, 1);
        }

        if (!isset($data['categories'][$key])) {
            $data['categories'][$key]['name'] = $key;
        }

        $data['categories'][$key]['manufacturer'][] = array(
            'name' => $result['name'],
            'href' => $this->url->link('product/manufacturer/info', 'manufacturer_id=' . $result['manufacturer_id']),
            'image' => $result['image'],
            'banner' => $result['banner'],
            'blurb' => $result['blurb'],
        );
    }

$data['brand_blurb'] = $manufacturer_info['blurb'];
```

This is where I am echoing the variable

```
<div class="brand_description"><?php echo $brand_blurb; ?></div>
```

Do you know what I might be doing wrong? I am still new to PHP so I appreciate the help.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declare `$data['brand_blurb']` but you echo `$brand_blurb`. Change one of the two.
so either:

```
$brand_blurb = $manufacturer_info['blurb'];
```

or:

```
<div class="brand_description"><?php echo $data['brand_blurb']; ?></div>
```

EDIT:

Maybe for some reason the characters are converted to Entity Numbers [freeformatter.com](http://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html).
for example
`<h1>testing</h1>` => `&lt;h1&gt;testing&lt;&#47;h1&gt;`

Try the following, `html_entity_decode()` [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

```
<div class="brand_description"><?php echo html_entity_decode($data['brand_blurb']); ?></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried that (both seem to work just fine) but the HTML is still rendered as plain text. The tags show us as plain text, they are not rendered as HTML.

Comment: Spot on, that solved the issue! Thank you very much Phil